# Azure Data Factory: Execute Pipeline activity cannot reference calling pipeline, cyclical behaviour required

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a number of pipelines that need to cycle depending on availability of data. If the data is not there wait and try again. The pipe behaviours are largely controlled by a database which captures logs which are used to make decisions about processing.

I read the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) about the `Execute Pipeline` activity which states that

> The Execute Pipeline activity allows a Data Factory or Synapse
> pipeline to invoke **another** pipeline.

It does not explicitly state that it is impossible though. I tried to reference `Pipe_A` from `Pipe_A` but the pipe is not visible in the drop down. I need a work-around for this restriction.

[image]

**Constraints**:

- The pipe must not call all pipes again, just the pipe in question. The preceding pipe is running all pipes in parallel.
- I don't know how many iterations are needed and cannot specify this quantity.
- As far as possible best effort has been implemented and this pattern should continue.

**Ideas**:

1. Create a intermediary pipe that **can** be referenced. **This is no good** I would need to do this for every pipe that requires this behaviour because dynamic content is not allowed for pipe selection. This approach would also pollute the Data Factory workspace.
2. Direct control flow backwards after waiting inside the same pipeline if condition is met. **This won't work either**, the `If` activity does not allow expression of flow within the same context as the `If` activity itself.
3. I thought about externalising this behaviour to a Python application which could be attached to an Azure Function if needed. The application would handle the scheduling and waiting. The application could call any pipe it needed and could itself be invoked by the pipe in question. This seems drastic!
4. Finally, I discovered an activity `Until` which has do while behaviour. I could wrap these pipes in `Until`, the pipe executes and finishes and sets database state to 'finished' or cannot finish and sets the state to incomplete and waits. The expression then either kicks off another execution or it does not. Additional conditional logic can be included as required in the procedure that will be used to set a value to variable used by the expression in the `Until`. I would need a variable per pipe.

[image]

**I *think* idea 4 makes sense**, I thought I would post this anyway in case people can spot limitations in this approach and/or recommend an approach.

Comment: 4th approach Seems perfect to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely agree with [All About BI,](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14997304/all-about-bi) its seems in your scenario the best suited ADF Activity is Until :

> The Until activity in ADF functions as a wrapper and parent component
> for iterations, with inner child activities comprising the block of
> items to iterate over. The result (s) from those inner child
> activities must then be used in the parent Until expression to
> determine if another iteration is necessary. Alternatively, if the
> pipeline can be maintained

The assessment condition for the `Until activity` might comprise outputs from other activities, pipeline parameters, or variables.

When used in conjunction with the `Wait activity`, the `Until activity` allows you to create loop conditions to periodically check the status of specific operations. Here are some examples:

- Check to see if the database table has been updated with new rows.
- Check to see if the SQL job is complete.
- Check to see whether any new files have been added to a specific
  folder.